# AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'fromWei'

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I have been receiving this error how do I solve it
AttributeError: 'Web3' object has no attribute 'fromWei'

I have tried toWei and plenty of other stuffs but nothing seem to work what do I do I really need someone to help me

Is it a problem with nodes cause I have tried all possible nodes and it still gave me the same error

Comment: How do you expect us to help without sharing your code?

Comment: Please show a minimal example and which package you are using that you expect to have a fromWei object.

Comment: Its possible that you want `from_wei`.

Answer (score 1):

Web3.py version 6.0 renamed all functions to snake_case to conform [PEP-8 style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

The correct function is `Web3.from_wei`.

See [Web3.py release notes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).